# Validate .CSV file

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, csv, validation

I have a csv file with the following columns and data:

| cod_emp | cod_departamento | cod_ciudad | iden_user | iden_responsable | cod_urgencia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 103452 | 52 | 520001 | 108324213 | 98741345 | 33 |
| 123491 | 65 | 654411 | 43212341 | 108432234 | 12 |
| 978451 | 12 | 124500 | 87412458 | 108745122 | 25 |

each column is a primary field of a table that i have in my sql server database:

**cod_emp** is a primary key of the table EMPLEADO,
**cod_departamento** is the primary key of the table DEPARTAMENTO, 
**cod_ciudad** is the primary of the table CIUDAD 
... and that goes for the other columns..
The validation is basically check each data of the csv and comparing it with the tables mentioned above like check if the value '103452' is in the table EMPLEADO and so goes on for every data of the csv.

Supposing that i have 500 rows in the csv, what is the best way to achieve this? loop through the csv and make a select statement for every data of the csv? i'm planning to code this in c#

Comment: It depends, how much data is in the tables in your database? And does a line in your CSV file contain data that is all related to eachother? So do you need to validate if the `cod_emp` value exists in your database and is linked to the `cod_departemento` value in that same CSV line?

Comment: @DeMaki yeah for example validate if  the value of cod_emp in the csv is in the table EMPLEADO of the DB, and for every column like iden_user validate if exist in the table USUARIO, for how many data is in the tables, there is many data in the tables EMPLEADO, USUARIO, and CIUDAD

Comment: For simplicity you can refer to CSVHelper: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/

Comment: It sounds like you need to validate each row, and in order to that you'll have to fetch the data from the database to validate against. You can reduce the number of round trips to the database, by bulk selecting data, but I would probably go for a first iteration that validates the CSV line by line. Avoid premature optimization. For smaller tables you could decide to simply fetch all records at once, put in a cache for quick validation. But start simple and get a performance baseline first. And as suggested by @Ugur, go for a framework to help processing the CSV.

Comment: @DeMaki could you please elaborate what is bulk selecting data? there is actually 30 columns in the csv that i need to validate with 30 tables of the DB